# Level of parallelism in pi calculation

Tags: parallel-processing, pi

I have been going through the code

```
npoints = 10000
circle_count = 0

p = number of tasks
num = npoints/p

find out if I am MASTER or WORKER 

do j = 1,num 
  generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 1
  xcoordinate = random1
  ycoordinate = random2
  if (xcoordinate, ycoordinate) inside circle
  then circle_count = circle_count + 1
end do

if I am MASTER

  receive from WORKERS their circle_counts
  compute PI (use MASTER and WORKER calculations)

else if I am WORKER

  send to MASTER circle_count

endif
```

can anyone tell what level of parallelism is used in this algorithm???
 i am asking the level of prallelism which are
 1)job or program level
 2)task or procedure level
 3)inter instruction level
 4)intra instruction level

Answer (score 0):

It's the monte carlo method, the more runs the more accurate result you will retrive.

```
  do j = 1,num 
  generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 1
  xcoordinate = random1
  ycoordinate = random2
  if (xcoordinate, ycoordinate) inside circle
  then circle_count = circle_count + 1
  end do
```

Code above is a monte carlo step, it can be parallelized in num threads running independent (as long as circle_count variable is shared between threads).
After all points created, you can go back to single thread to compute pi value.

Comment: thanks. but i am asking the level of prallelism which are
1)job or program level
2)task or procedure level
3)inter instruction level
4)intra instruction level